# How can I skip characters I can't read when reading aloud?

Tags: spoken

As an example, I was at the cinema and I wanted to buy tickets for a film named

> 北京遇上西雅图

However, I can't read all of the characters.

In English I'd say;

> Can I get a ticket for that film "北京*something*上西*something**something*", please?

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Chinese?

Comment: obviously this doesn't happen in the same way in English, but if a name is very long, it's not uncommon to forget some of it "lemony snickets: a series of *something* *something*"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use 什么, or 什么什么 as the placeholder for the characters I can't read.

In your exmaple, I would say: 北京 **什么** 西 **什么**, or 北京 **什么什么** 西 **什么什么**, or 北京 **什么** 西 **什么什么**, or 北京 **什么什么** 西 **什么**.

什么 or 什么什么 can substitute any numbers of characters.

I am from Northern China, and I am not sure what words people in other regions in China would use for this purpose.

Comment: if there were two characters, would you repeat the "什么"?

Comment: @MatthewRudy马泰 As he says, "什么 or 什么什么 can substitute any numbers of characters".

Comment: @MatthewRudy马泰: I revised my answer after seeing your comment.

Comment: @孤影萍踪 yeah. I wrote my comment, then saw your update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

many people read:北京X（音：叉cha）上西XX

Comment: that's an interesting suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I don't get it... :P

Comment: Probably more appropriate in writing. In speech, chā has other... more sexual connotations and should be discouraged in this context.